# Como copiar la estructura de un DF para leer otro DF con esa estructura - PYSPARK

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

estoy intentando certificar dos DF de diferentes ambientes. El primero se encuentra cargado en HUE y el segundo en un servidor SQL.

Para la certificación he creado una llave concatenando todas las columnas en un registro para ambos ambos DF para posteriormente hacer un join entre ellos y ver cual ha quedado Null. En la concatenacion de campos me he encontrado con problemas por el tipo de datos ya que en HUE esta como Int y en SQL está como Float (cuando hago la concatenación el punto del float cambia toda la llave). Es por ello que busco traer la estructura del DF que esta en HUE y esta pasársela al momento de la carga del DF de SQL a través de StructType. A continuación el código:

Con ello obtengo los tipos de datos del DF de HUE

```
dlschema = tabla_dl.dtypes
```

Lo que arroja el siguiente resultado:
`print(dlschema)`

```
 ('rut', 'decimal(9,0)'),
 ('dv', 'string'),
 ('numeropersonaaltair', 'int'),
 ('nombre', 'string'),
 ('direccionparticular', 'string'),
 ('codcomunaparticular', 'smallint'),
 ('fonoparticular', 'string'),
 ('celularparticular', 'string'),
 ('direccioncomercial', 'string')]
```

Luego de ello busco darle el formato para usarlo en StructType. El formato debe ser de esta manera para usarlo en la lectura del DF de SQL.   :

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
])
```

```
list_st = ""
for i in range(len(dlschema)):
    if str(dlschema[i][1]).find('decimal') >= 0:
        data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).replace('decimal','DecimalType').replace("'","") + ")"
    elif str(dlschema[i][1]).find('smallint') >= 0:
        data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).replace('smallint','IntegerType()').replace("'","") + ")"
    elif str(dlschema[i][1]).find('bigint') >= 0:
        data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).replace('bigint','IntegerType()').replace("'","") + ")"  
    elif str(dlschema[i][1]).find('int') >= 0:
        data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).replace('int','IntegerType()').replace("'","") + ")"
    elif str(dlschema[i][1]).find('string') >= 0:
        data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).replace('string','StringType()').replace("'","") + ")"
    elif str(dlschema[i][1]).find('date') >= 0:
        data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).replace('date','DateType()').replace("'","") + ")"
   
   # else:
   #     data = "('" + str(dlschema[i][0]) + "'," + str(dlschema[i][1]).title() + "Type())"

    list_st += ",StructField" + data
print("[" + list_st[1:] + "]")
```

El output es el siguiente:

```
        [StructField('periodo',DateType()),StructField('rut',DecimalType(9,0)),StructField('dv',StringType()),StructField('numeropersonaaltair',IntegerType()),StructField('nombre',StringType()),StructField('direccionparticular',StringType()),StructField('codcomunaparticular',IntegerType()),StructField('fonoparticular',StringType()),StructField('celularparticular',StringType()),StructField('direccioncomercial',StringType())]
```

Como pueden ver, he hecho la conversión para dejar la sentencia igual al uso de StructType pero no puedo pasarla como variable cuando cargo el DF ya que lo lee como variable string.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

no has probado hacer esto `tabla_dl.schema` ... esto deberia de imprimir el schema.
Veo que el schema que has generado no inicia con StructType.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).